# Swift: How can I use synchronized thread for Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to use synchronized thread using Alamofire.

I am using like this code for synchronization.

```
    let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1")
    let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue2")
    queue1.async {
        self.dataFromServer.getData()
    }
    queue2.async {
        //check if success to get the data from server
        while(!self.dataFromServer.resultData){}

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // do something on screen
        }
    }
```

...

```
   func getData() {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
           if response.error == nil {
            // get data
            self.resultData = true
           }else{
            // error
           }
        }
   }
```

I want to do something after get data from server using Alamofire.
Is this correct?
If this is not good, please tell me about the synchronization please.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another and probably the good way of doing it by using closures.

```
// You don't need to create queue and it asynchronously, since Alamofire calls are async.
// You can  remove queue statement
let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1")
queue1.async {
    self.dataFromServer.getData(completionClosure: { (resultData) in
        if resultData {

        }
        else {

        }
    })
}
```

Then in your function have a parameter that takes a closure and call it with success or failure boolean.

```
func getData(completionClosure: (Bool) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        if response.error == nil {
            // get data
            completionClosure(true)
        }
        else{
            completionClosure(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your help is very useful for me.
It works well!

Answer (score 0):

you can call

```
dispatch_sync
```

instead of async  or you can call other API in the success block of first API

Comment: Thank you!
But I can't call dispatch_sync in my project.
Why I can't see this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `getData()` function to return block so that you get callback on the sucess of the api call

```
func getData(sucess:((Void) -> Void)?) {
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
           if response.error == nil {
            // get data
            sucess!()
            self.resultData = true
           }else{
            // error
           }
        }
}
```

Do whatever you want to do after the api response has received in the sucess callback of the `getData()` function

Comment: Thank you for your help.